# Highcharts Control Basic DrilDown Using Dom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the answer of my previous question on how to use DOM to do the drilldown and up at [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908249/issue-on-drilling-down-and-up-in-highcharts-js-using-external-dom-buttons). But I found a simple and easy to understand version of highcharts.js at [Here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown) which as you can see the code is more clear to understand.

Now can you please let me know how to enable buttons to do the drilldown and up in [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/vncnwd66/1/)?

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    function drawChart1() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Basic drilldown'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
             credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Things',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'Animals',
                    y: 5,
                    drilldown: 'animals'
                }, {
                    name: 'Fruits',
                    y: 2,
                    drilldown: 'fruits'
                }]
            }],
            drilldown: {
                series: [{
                    id: 'animals',
                    data: [
                        ['Cats', 4],
                        ['Dogs', 2],
                        ['Cows', 1],
                        ['Sheep', 2],
                        ['Pigs', 1]
                    ]
                }, {
                    id: 'fruits',
                    data: [
                        ['Apples', 4],
                        ['Oranges', 2]
                    ]
                }]
            }
        });

        $("#animals").on("click", function () {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $("#overview").removeClass('disabled');
        });
        $("#fruits").on("click", function () {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $("#overview").removeClass('disabled');
        });
        $("#overview").on("click", function () {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $("#animals").removeClass('disabled');
            $("#fruits").removeClass('disabled');
        });
    }
    drawChart1();

});
```

Comment: I found a solution for getting back(drillup)  into the overview by using `chart.drillUp();` but for drilldown the `chart.drilldown.series[0];` is not working! Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not part of the API, but as you noticed, to drill up, you need to call `chart.drillUp()`. To drilldown, it's a bit different and depends where you want drilldown.

In short call method: `chart.xAxis[0].drilldownCategory(category_index);`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/vncnwd66/2/

However, there is one limitation: you can't drilldown from second level of A, to the second level of B. First you will need to drill up, then drilldown to the another second level.